# View cmd.exe console from Scheduled Task batch in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: batch-file, console, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

In Windows Server 2008 R2 I am running a batch as a Scheduled Task.
I know this is not usually the case, but I *want* to view the cmd.exe console window when it is running.  Note that 'Hidden' under the General tab in Task Scheduler is not selected.
I have tried ECHO ON.  When I double-click the .bat file, the console window opens.
How can I watch this batch run in console with a Scheduled Task?

Comment: Thanks very much for the link.  The task is already running under the logged on user account, and 'Run whether user is logged on or not'.  This link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293(v=vs.85).aspx has a white paper download that explains the "Session 0 Isolation" security changes that lead to not being able to view cmd.exe running in a scheduled task.  There may still be a way around it, but I will need to figure that out from here (or not :).  If I figure something out I will post it.  In absence of that, I can always pipe it to a log file.

Comment: Not worth attempting to override security -- piping to a log file.

Comment: Doesn't work that way.  The first user to log on is session 1.  It doesn't matter if you are admin or other user.